# connecting to laser too long and nothing happens (after reinstallation virtualbox & ubuntu)

Tags: sicklms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,

i have lms100 laser scanner, a few days ago i can connect with laser by "rosrun lms1xx LMS1xx_node" code.
yesterday i decided to delete everything like ubuntu in virtualbox and virtualbox itself ( because i have not enough space and didnt manage to expand actual size). Then i installed everything again (vitualbox, ubuntu, ros and ofcourse lms1xx). Everything was ok, but when i try to connect laser by the same way, it said "connecting to laser at " but nothings happen, the process is sooo long, after ~5 min it says [ WARN] [1462876612.290873681]: Unable to connect, retrying.

i dont know what's wrong, what did i forget to do?

update: i checked in "rostopic list" in another terminal, and it responds like

/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan

so i tried "rostopic info /scan" and respond was

Type: sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Publishers:

- /lms1xx (http://basak-VirtualBox:43812/)

Subscribers: None

Thanks, Basak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234041/connecting-to-laser-too-long-and-nothing-happens-(after-reinstallation-virtualbox-&-ubuntu)/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
Can you connect other USB devices to Virtualbox?

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-10**:
I didnt try before because i didnt need it. I connect laser sensor via ethernet...but now i tried to connect usb and it can connect

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
What are Virtual Computer's and laser scanner's IPs?

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-10**:
I know the IP's of laser scanner and when i made a connection with laser scanner in ros i wrote the IP of laser but i dont know what is the IP of virtual computer...you think my problem is because of IP's?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
May be. You can see your ip via `ifconfig` command. You should probably see the `eth0` section. Also You don't need port number if you are using port in your launch file. (for ex: `192.168.0.1:<PORT_NUMBER>`).

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
And be sure your laser and computer on the same network
(Both IPs are `192.168.1.x` or Both `192.168.0.x` etc.)

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-10**:
is "inet addr" my virtual computer's IP? if so, they are different...but i'm sure the IP of LMS100, i checked from its own program SOPAS...what should i do? kafayı yemek üzereyim :D

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
Yes, it is your ip adress. And it's be same without last part of it(`192.168.1.x`). Try ping command to your laser for finding what's going on, just open terminal on ubuntu and type:
`ping <ip of laser>`.
And Forum's language is English, We must use English only :)

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-10**:
i did it and the results are like these...PING 169.254.10.200 (169.254.10.200) 56(84) bytes of data.

^C
--- 169.254.10.200 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7999ms

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
Alright, You can't ping to device, so there is a network problem. What's your IP adress? Can you write?

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-10**:
It was 194.27.66.92 when i run ifconfig code in the terminal.

**Comment by [cereensare](https://answers.ros.org/users/99983/cereensare/) on 2022-03-21**:
Hi, I have lms141 laser scanner.  I have the ubuntu 20.04 and I use noetic distro on my computer. I can't connect to laser by "rosrun lms1xx LMS1xx_node _host:=192.168.2.74". I took the laser's IP address from SOPAS and set the computer's IP address but it did't work. I checked the rostopic list and it's same as basak's. What should I do? It's really complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this. When i was rethinking what did i do differently in this installation and i found it. It was my mistake which i made in reinstallation. When i reinstall virtualbox and ubuntu by watching a tutorial video, i chose "bridged adaptor" in network section by following that tutorial and it leads me into this problem. So i changed bridged adaptor to original version which is NAT, the problem is solved. Now i can ping the laser's IP and i can connect with it.

---

Originally posted by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) with karma: 73 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To setup `eth0` to static, open `/etc/network/interfaces` via `gedit` or `nano` in command line:

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then, edit file with these informations (I assigned 3, You can select 1-254 and different from laser, 200):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.254.10.3 
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.254.1.254
```

Then save file with `Ctrl + X` with nano, and type this commands on terminal,

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

The Computer may not be connect to internet after doing this, Try changes above, Try ping to laser:

```
ping 192.254.10.200
```

If it will / won't works, change the file to

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And also `sudo service network-manager` to restart network, then Internet will be up. Write here If it works or not.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-11**:
you were right it was network problem...i didn't have a chance to try your solution but thanks to you i realize what was the problem. thank you a lot for your help :)